# Bash: Confused by expanding asterisk

Tags: bash

I have a very simple scripts called `test.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(cat './data')

while read line
do
  data=$data' '$line
done < './data'
echo $data
```

And the `data` file:

```
1 * 1 = 1
```

But actually bash(4.3.11)/dash(sh 0.5.7) expands asterisk itself. It prints out

```
1 test.sh data 1 = 1
1 test.sh data 1 = 1
```

Zsh(5.0.2) won't act like this.

I don't know why. How can I print out using bash

```
1 * 1 = 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yep. `echo` here is useless. It's just a part of a large one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule #1, quote your variables!

```
echo "$(cat data)"
```

and

```
data="$data $line"
```

and

```
echo "$data"
```

Although as [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) pointed out in the comments below (since removed), the second of the three changes is actually unnecessary, as glob expansion does not occur during variable assignment.

That said, if you just want to print the contents of the file, there's no need to use a command substitution or `read` loop at all. Why not just use `cat data`?

Alternatively, to store the contents of the file to a variable, just use `data="$(cat data)"` (the quotes are important here), or as suggested in the comments above by gniourf_gniourf, `data="$(< data)"`.

Comment: @jasonz please see my updated answer, I believe it addresses your problems.

Comment: Thanks. `echo` here is useless. It's just a part of a large script which i store the contents of the file to a variable.